# wp_query inside the_loop

Tags: loop

I am having this issue with my loops. I am making a shortcode that will be called from the main query. It will display on the front page from the_loop. for some reason that I can't figure out. The second query displays only one post when it should display 3. So the shortcode will go in the page content. In the settings section, I have the front page set as static to "Home" and the blog page set to "Blog" but home is not a template. It is being generated by the index.php page using WordPress 2014 theme. So in the "Home" page content area, I have the shortcode that generates the second loop to get 3 posts from a category called "featured".

```
 $featured = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => $category, 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) );
   if( $featured->have_posts()) : while( $featured->have_posts()): $featured->the_post();
 global $more;
 $more = 0;

 the_title();

 the_content( '<a class="clear" href="'.get_permalink().'"><img class="button" src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/read-more.png" alt="read more" height="32" width="85" /></a>' );

endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

This loop will display the first of the three posts but not the other two.

I also tried using get_posts but that didn't work out any better

Comment: The code works for me with known good values.

Comment: The one post that returns, can you check if it's a post, not a page ? if page, try adding `'post_type' => 'post'`. If it's a post, then try adding `'suppress_filters' => true`. If none of it works, then there's other solutions too.

Comment: This did not work. I thought it was because the return statement was not in the loop. When I added inside the loop, it displayed the third post instead of the first. Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with following code:

```
$featured = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => $category, 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) );

// The Loop
if ( $featured->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $featured->have_posts() ) {
        $featured->the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<div id="title">' . get_the_title() .'</div>';
        echo '<div id="content">' . get_the_content() .'</div>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```